# Do Bane bonuses from multiple sources stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage

I am playing an Inquisitor who has the "bane ability" in which I can change my bane type that I apply each round I so choose for a certain number of rounds per day. My sword already has (evil outsider) bane on it. We are playing Wrath of the Righteous, which includes lots of demons.

If I use my Inquisitor power to put "demon bane" on my sword that already has evil outsider bane, and attack an evil (outsider) demon, do the banes stack as they are from separate sources and differing types of bane that would both effect the same creature? (such as when people put multiple energy types on the same weapon, but they still stack for damage)

As the bane is not an enhancement bonus itself, but a modification of one, it should stack with anything on the weapon. I would reason that the two differing types of bane would add together only in instances in which they both applied, of course, but would be similar to the elemental damage rules where differing types do stack.

My question is more in relation to the differing sources (ability vs. weapon already imbued). If this makes bane viable two ways, then the damage is a no brainer, but does this in fact function the way that I think it does? Any input is very much welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

The double bane does not stack because the [class specifically](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor) states

> At 5th level, an inquisitor can imbue one of her weapons with the bane weapon special ability as a swift action.

So clearly both are the same source of bane and you cant stack them in anyway that you could benefit from both, except maybe a better caster level.

Comment: Both are being placed on the weapon, yes. However, one is magically imbued to the weapon upon creation and the other is an ability. This ability does not state anything about banes from differing sources not stacking. Is there somewhere in the rules that the rules do? This is what I was trying to find out. I do not believe your reference is entirely clear on this matter and await further information.Again, I reference the

Comment: Again, I reference the elemental additions to swords as a parallel, two different element types stack, why not two bane types from alternate sources? Even if the +2 to weapon did not stack, I do not see why the damage would not as it is a differing type. Please explain further if I am missing something.

Comment: @Krista Because the source of both *banes* isn't the inquisitor himself nor the inquisitor's special ability nor, likewise, isn't the sword's creator nor the  creator's spells that made the sword or whatever, but, in both cases, *only* the magic weapon special ability *bane*. A *+1 flaming shocking sword* deals an extra +1d6 points of fire damage and an extra +1d6 points of electrical damage, but a *+1 flaming flaming sword* still deals but an extra +1d6 fire damage and, therefore, a *+1 outsider (demon) bane outsider (demon) bane longsword* deals only an extra +2d6 points of damage to demons.

Comment: Ok, you reference the elemental additions. Notice how there are multiple elemental additions and only one bane? So while they are similar, they are not the same.

Comment: Actually there are numerous types of bane, evil outsider, demon, elf, etc. The list goes on. At the time of forging a weapon only one can be chosen. Mythic bane, for instance specifically says it stacks with other banes, does that mean an inquisitor with the bane ability is in no way truly helping himself by having a bane weapon, as those slots could be used for other things and they don't stack?

Comment: I admit almost total ignorance of mythic rules. Bare in mind that mythic rules often make drastic changes to how the base something works.

Comment: The only way I could see a bane weapon helping an inquisitor would be by allowing the inquisitor to be attacking two different types of enemies at once. If you have a +1 bane (elves) scimitar, adding your inquisitor bane (goblin) ability would allow you to attack an evil elf and his goblin side kick in the same round. In this instance, it's not stacking, but you are benefiting.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan  and mister ducky - you mention the elemental damage and what stacks and what doesn't with that (the exact same element). But if that were translated to differing banes being allowed per situation referenced above, and as ducky said elf and goblin being allowed... If that were switched to my original types ( one evil outsider and one demon). I can see the +2 to the sword not stacking as it IS the same type (generic bane increase), but the damage... For instance fighting a devil (demon not helpful, but evil outsider is) 2d6 +2 (from the bane making the weapon 2higher)

Comment: However, versus a Demon, it would be like the flaming and electric, 4d6 +2 ( as the generic bane only counts once, but the BANE TYPES both count against the same creature). Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @Krista This is more contentious than I originally thought. You can read more [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2oz5y&page=1?Do-bane-weapon-special-abilities-stack).